# How to convert 0.5 to 0.50 in php

Tags: php

Is there a possibility to display "0.5" as "0.50" in php?

I don't mean something like that:

```
<?php
    $x = 0.5;
    echo($x . "0");
?>
```

So this can fit in too:

```
$x = 0.75;
```

I hope my question is exact enough.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Do:**

```
$x = 0.5;
printf("%.2f", $x);
```

**Get:**

```
0.50
```

**Explanation:**

[`printf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) and [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) can print/return a formatted string. There are plenty of [format parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php#refsect1-function.sprintf-parameters) available. Here, I used `%.2f`. Let's take that apart:

- `%` denotes a placeholder that will be replaced with `$x`
- `.` denotes a *precision specifier*
- `2` belongs to the precision specifier - *the number of digits after the decimal point*
- `f` is the *type specifier*, here *float* as that's what we're passing in

**Alternatively:**

Use [`number_format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php):

```
echo number_format($x, 2);
```

Here, `2` denotes the number of decimal digits you want in the output. You don't actually need to supply a third and fourth parameter, as their defaults are exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Use number_format() function

```
echo number_format($x,  2, '.', '');
```

Comment: Ok fixed , not tested

Answer (score 0):

Use `number_format` Function

```
<?php
print number_format('0.5',2,'.','');

// 0.50
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Answer (score 0):

You need to use number_format

```
 $x = 0.5;
 echo number_format($x, 2, '.', '');
```

Output = 0.50

Answer (score 0):

i think use..
sprintf("%.02f",$string);
Or number_format()